# Best software to edit your photos (red-eye correction etc.)

Tags: windows, editing, photos

My mother wants me to correct her photos (red eye, some other defects). But, actually, I don't know what tool I can use on Windows for digital photo editing. Preferably, free of course. I was going to try F-Spot for that, but found, that it's available only on Linux.

Can you suggest something cool for photo editing? I need to edit, NOT organize.

GIMP is too complex, Paint .NET seem not to be capable of extended correction functions.

Comment: Picasa not good enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Picasa](http://www.picasa.com) has a pretty good red-eye removal tool - it automatically detects red eyes in the photo and you just click "Apply". So you could ignore its organising capabilities and just use it as an editor.

Answer (score 2):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) Is another choice.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [**FastStone Image Viewer**](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm).

> FastStone Image Viewer is a fast,
>   stable, user-friendly image browser,
>   converter and editor. It has a nice
>   array of features that include image
>   viewing, management, comparison,
>   red-eye removal, emailing, resizing,
>   cropping and color adjustments.

[image]